# Public access to Jenkins Dev at Cloud from Cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, public, cloudbees

I would like to open publicly my Jenkins instance from dev@cloud. I can't see any option in the GUI. I also searched through the documentation and I don't see any chapter where this is discussed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In `/configure`, check *Enable read-only access for anonymous users*. This opens up everything to the world. You can fine-tune permissions first using [role-based access control](https://documentation.cloudbees.com/docs/cje-user-guide/rbac.html) (until this box is checked, anonymous users will be directed to log in regardless of RBAC configuration).